# How does one consume public, cross domain json data in single page frameworks like backbone marionette?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, marionette

Man is this a tough question to get properly stated because there are so many gaps in my knowledge in the "public API" and "cross domain" spaces.

Maybe the best way to do it is just to give a real world example:

I've got a backbone marionette app.  It's cool.  It's doing lots of stuff I want it to do.

I've also got some really cool charts - a commercial HTML5 charting library.  I want to make use of the charting library in my bb marionette app.

Here's the key.  The data I want to show in the charts is not mine.  It's campaign finance data offered by the NY Times API (http://developer.nytimes.com/docs).  It's also other data offered in other public api's.

In my head I figured I'd just wire my bb marionette data model to the json URL the NY Times provides, call a model.fetch(), parse json data returned, bind the data to my charts, and I'm golden.  Can't get the data though because that's a cross domain request - a no no in JavaScript.  So people say "simple, just implement cors".  Can't do that.  I don't control the NY Times servers so I can't add "Allow Access Control" to headers on the resource.  Same goes for other public api's I'm trying to use.  I think "implement cors" is for cases where "you" control the server.

So others write "...you can write a server side wrapper on your website that calls the NY Times API. And then you have your client side JavaScript call your wrapper. Since they are on the same domain, you avoid the cross-site scripting issues.

your client code --> your server side wrapper --> NYT API

Makes sense in theory.  Is this what the publishers of such API's, like the NY Times, or weather services, or financial data services, etc., expect people to do when they say "our api is public"?  Is this the workflow that is assumed - consume with your server app and relay to your marionette client app?  Is this the "bb Marionetty" way to do this?  What am I missing here about the conventions involved?  How do developers typically consume public API's if not via client side JavaScript calls (like model.fetch())?

My server back end for my bb marionette app is ASP.NET Web API.  Am I supposed to some how wire my bb marionette model to my own ASP.NET Web API and have my Web API call the NY Times service?  My understanding of the general "public API" principle is not solid here so I can't arrive at a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense that they call it a "public API" because it is open for every user. No need to login with a special account or credential.

The problem comes from the client, in this case, the browser. It is the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) for a security concern. It is not "a no no in Javascript", you can do that in a node.js environment as well.

Your way to solve that is a good way named proxy, you can get more details about it from [this article](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html). It is commonly used by many web sites.

Another way is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Most js libs/frameworks such as JQuery have a wrapper for it. It has some limitations but can be done without extra server-side code.

In your case, I think proxy is an almost best practice (maybe there are better ones). You can finely control the results, handle errors, decorated them or even persist them for your web page.

Comment: I think what I'm missing is the general purpose of a public API like NYT.  What is the expected client or use of it and others like it?  They obviously expect others are going to use their services and data.  They obviously know about browser same origin policy.  Who do they expect will be using their stuff then?  World kind of operates in browsers now.  Is my use of the data in charts in a browser the wrong use?  Or are other servers, like my ASP.NET Web API, indeed, the primary consumers of such data and services?  In other words I'm looking to use these services and data as intended.  Am I?

Comment: The api only requires a client can send http requests. They definitely know that many users use the data for web page content. But standing as a service provider, what can you do? It's the browser's behavior for security. Even that you can disable the same origin policy (most browsers have a config for it), you let your site expose to a script injection risk. That's almost every API provider does. Check the Facebook feed api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/. They require POST, which in browser you almost can't send via an ajax if you are crossing domains.

Comment: I think "your client code --> your server side wrapper --> NYT API" is good, and future-proof.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I'm not arguing for less security.  I see the reasoning and agree with it.  I'm more trying to see what others faced with the landscape do. So here's what I'm going to try:  Marionette model.fetch() calls Web API controller.  Controller calls NY Times service and gets data (haven't done this before.  Have to research).  Controller returns json data to Marionette client which parses and tells chart to re-render.  Will report result here and mark accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When API providers say their stuff is public but they don't implement CORS, you can usually assume their intention is for you to call the call the API from your own server which will do authentication and caching as-appropriate so that API keys aren't exposed to users and your users aren't utilizing excessive resources on their side.